# Python: List Calendars using Google Calendar API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am trying to list my account's Google Calendars using the Calendar API, but it is returning `No Calendars Found`.

Below is my code:

`models/cal_setup.py`

```
import pickle
import os.path
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# You can change the scope of the application, make sure to delete token.pickle file first
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'     # Give path to your credentials.json file


def get_calendar_service():

    cred = None

    '''
    The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created automatically when
    the authorization flow completes for the first time. In other words when the user give access to this 
    channel
    '''

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle','rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)
    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)
    service = build('calendar','v3',credentials=cred)
    return service
```

`calendar.py`

```
from models.cal_setup import get_calendar_service

def list_cal():

    print("List all calendar")
    service = get_calendar_service()

    print('Getting list of calendars')
    calendars_result = service.calendarList().list().execute()

    calendars = calendars_result.get('items', [])

    if not calendars:
        print('No calendars found.')
    for calendar in calendars:
        summary = calendar['summary']
        id = calendar['id']
        primary = "Primary" if calendar.get('primary') else ""
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (summary, id, primary))

list_cal()
```

I am using a key generated from the Google Cloud service account to achieve this and below is its permissions:

[image]

I have added my email account as an owner.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Correction you are trying to list the calendars that are currently stored in the calendarList.  Which is the bottom left hand corer of the Google calendar website.  By default nothing is in that unless you manually add it except the users primary calendar.

You are using a service account and by default it has nothing in its calendar list. You need to delegate to a user on your workspace domain so that it will list the calendars that user has added to their calendar list.

To be 100% clear calendars list will not give you a list of all the calendars a user has access to.  There is no method that will do that.  You can have access to a calendar without it appearing in your calendar list.

## delegation

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH = "C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\workspaceserviceaccount.json"


def create_calendar_service(user_email):
    """Build and return a calendar service object authorized with the service
  account that acts on behalf of the given user.

  Args:
    user_email: The email of the user to impersonate. Needs permissions to access Cloud Search.
  Returns:
    Cloud Search Query API service object that is ready to make requests.
  """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=SCOPES)

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email) # user to delegate as

    return build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)


def main(user_email):
    service = create_calendar_service(user_email)
    results = service.calendarList().get(calendarId='primary').execute()
    print(results['summary'])

    page_token = None
    while True:
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for event in events['items']:
            print(event['summary'])
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("xxx@daimto.com")
```

Comment: How do you import `ServiceAccountCredentials` ?

Comment: Here you might as well have my full sample